# Routing and Navigation in SAPUI5 not working

Tags: sapui5

I have some problem with routing defined in mainfest.json. 
But when I am navigating to 'App_Split2' it is going to  view 'ExpenseSm' of 'App_Split1' for all other Pattern it is wokring fine even for 'splitStatus'

(Both App_Split1 & App_Split2) are Master-detail

Below are Routes Details:

```
"routes": [{
                "pattern"           : "",
                "name"              : "Login",
                "view"              : "Login",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern"           : "LanchPad",
                "name"              : "Main",
                "view"              : "Main",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern"           : "NewExpense",
                "name"              : "ExpenseN",
                "view"              : "ExpenseN",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern"           : "Chart",
                "name"              : "ExpenseC",
                "view"              : "ExpenseC",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern"           : "splitStatus",
                "name"              : "App_Split1",
                "view"              : "App_Split1",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                    "subroutes": [
                    {
                    "pattern"           : "Master",
                    "name"              : "ExpenseSm",
                    "view"              : "ExpenseSm",
                    "targetAggregation" : "masterPages",
                    "targetControl"     : "idSplitContainer1"
                    },
                    {
                        "pattern"           : "{Tripnumber}",
                        "name"              : "ExpenseSd",
                        "view"              : "ExpenseSd",
                        "targetAggregation" : "detailPages"
                    }]
                },
                {
                "pattern"           : "splitApproval",
                "name"              : "App_Split2",
                "view"              : "App_Split2",
                "targetAggregation" : "pages",
                "targetControl"     : "idAppControl",
                    "subroutes": [
                    {
                    "pattern"           : "Master",
                    "name"              : "ExpenseMam",
                    "view"              : "ExpenseMam",
                    "targetAggregation" : "masterPages",
                    "targetControl"     : "idSplitContainer2"
                    },
                    {
                        "pattern"           : "{Usrid}",
                        "name"              : "ExpenseMad",
                        "view"              : "ExpenseMad",
                        "targetAggregation" : "detailPages"
                    }]
                }
        ]
```

Comment: FYI: subroutes are deprecated

Comment: Guide me how to avoid "subroutes" in above example

For single SplitContainer (MD) above route is working but when defining another SplitContainer(MD) in above route , It is not working.. Navigating to wrong View.

Comment: Thanks Marc it is  working now by changing subroutes to targets.